# Uploadify Show Error Message

Tags: uploadify

I use uploadify plugin v3.2.1, the problem is, I use file limit, but when I upload file above that limit it is not showing any error message. I've tried to find on google and found out that I need more codes just like this

```
'onSelectError' : function() {
        alert('The file ' + file.name + ' returned an error and was not added to the queue.');
    }
```

But still not work, anyone know? Maybe is in query file, but I don't know how to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
onSelectError': function (file, errorCode, errorMsg) {
        alert('The file ' + file.name + ' returned an error and was not added to the queue.');
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for other readers.